# After click outside the modal video play in background

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I have an iframe in the model in the model it plays the video but when I click outside the modal. The modal box is close but video play in the background.

My code:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg modalsize col-9 col-xs-12" id="mysliderVideo1" style="padding-top: 80px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <iframe class="video_container embed-responsive-item v_responsive"  height="50"  src="https://youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $page_info[0]['link1']; ?>?rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"  allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

 <section id="gallery" class="bg-lighter">
  <div class="container-fluid pt-70 pb-0">
    <div class="section-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div id="grid" class="gallery-isotope grid-4 gutter clearfix">

       <?php if(!empty($page_info[0]['link1'])){ ?>
       <div class="gallery-item photography" onclick='video_link("<?php echo $page_info[0]['link1']?>",)'>
           <div class="price pt-30">
                <h5 class="text-uppercase letter-space-2"></h5>
           </div>
         <div class="thumb galerryVideoCopy inset">
        <img src="<?php echo 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$page_info[0]['link1'].'/hqdefault.jpg' ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mysliderVideo1" />
        </div>
        </div>
           <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function video_link(url){
var temp = "https://youtube.com/embed/"+url+"?rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&autoplay=1";
$('.video_container').attr({
   src: temp 
 });
}
</script>
```

I want that if modal is close then video audio needs to stop or video does not play in the background.
Please help in this I do not know where my code is wrong.

Comment: if you click out of  `modal` it terminates the modal view but your `HTML` element still exists in background. So when you are closing your modal. you still also need to forcefulllly stop you current playing video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.video_container').attr({
      src: '', 
    });
});
```

Hope help.